# iOS Push notification set up One Signal Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, onesignal

I am new to OneSignal as I used to use appCenter.
I need to enable push notifications but I am not clear on the following:

1. Can I just use an APNS Key and an existing certificate that is notification enabled?

If not how many Certificate do I need? Do I need to create both a Distribution certificate and an Apple Push Notificatoin Service?

With appcenter I used to just have an APNS Key.Can someone clarify this for me

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I just use an APNS Key and an existing certificate that is notification enabled?

Actually, that can't.

> If not how many Certificate do I need? Do I need to create both a Distribution certificate and an Apple Push Notificatoin Service?

Yes, you need to create both of them.

**Distribution Certificate**: Used for publishing to AppStore or Ad-Hoc.

**Apple Push Notificatoin Service**: Used for pushing notification.

The difference is **Apple Push Notificatoin Service** not need to generate a provisioning profile , just export the Certificate to `.p12` file, and upload to OneSignal. However, Distribution also need to generate a provisioning profile, that's a noraml publishing process.

Here you just need to upload the `.p12` file to OneSignal.

More info can refer to [Create A Certificate Request Manually](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate#method-2-create-a-certificate-request-manually).

Comment: thanks for the reply that clarified it! however can you tell me we cannot use APNS Key only. I did that with appcenter. Is this Onesignal specific?

Comment: @developer9969 Yes, that's Onesignal specific. And generally third party push will use the `.p12` file. It seems that App Center Push is different with them.